# Sidebar login widget with error print, returns an error

Tags: login, widgets, forms

i'm building a widget to login from the sidebar and print errors if any,
so everything is working fine except that when i login it returns an error:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent.....

the code of the widget:

```
<?php
// Custom Login/Meta Widget
function widget_artdev_meta() { ?>

<?php global $user_ID, $user_identity, $user_level ?>
<?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>
<div class="widget">
 <h2>Control Panel</h2>
 <ul>
  <li>Identified as <strong><?php echo $user_identity ?></strong>.
  <ul>
   <?php if ( $user_level >= 10 ) : ?>
   <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-admin">Dashboard</a></li>
   <?php endif // $user_level >= 10 ?>

   <?php if ( $user_level >= 1 ) : ?>
   <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-admin/post-new.php">Write an article</a></li>
   <?php endif // $user_level >= 1 ?>

   <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/profile">Profile &amp; personal options</a></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); ?>" title="Exit">Exit</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>

<?php elseif ( get_option('users_can_register') ) : ?>

<?php
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'log-in' ) :
 global $error;
 $login = wp_login( $_POST['log'], $_POST['pwd'] );
 $login = wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $_POST['log'], 'user_password' => $_POST['pwd'], 'remember' => $_POST['rememberme'] ), false );
endif;
?>

<div class="widget">
 <h2>Identification</h2>

 <?php if ( $error ) : ?>
  <p class="error">
   <?php echo $error; ?>
  </p><!-- .error -->
 <?php endif; ?>

 <ul>
  <li>
  <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
   <label for="log">Customer ID
    <input type="text" name="log" id="log" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars(stripslashes($user_login), 1) ?>" size="22" class="input_text_login alignright" />
   </label>
   <label for="pwd">Password
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" size="22" class="input_text_login alignright" />
   </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" style="margin-right:35px; width:70px;" />
    <input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> Remember me
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="log-in" />
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"/>
  </form>
  </li>
  <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Recover password</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/register">Register</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<?php endif // get_option('users_can_register') ?>
<?php }
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar_widget') )
register_sidebar_widget(__('&rarr; Login/Meta Widget','artdev'), 'widget_artdev_meta');
?>
```

anyone out there can help?
i can't understand where the problem is...!

thanks a lot!
Philip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't use both `wp_login()` and `wp_signon()`. They do the same thing, but first one is deprecated
- Use the [2.8 widget API](http://jessealtman.com/2009/06/08/tutorial-wordpress-28-widget-api/)
- Put `wp_signon()` inside a function that you hook on the `init` tag (You can handle the errors in the `widget()` function)

Comment: thanks a lot AmbitiousAmoeba,
i will take a deep look and i'll come back with the results